# Saving class objects in robot framework

Tags: python, class, object, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework. I am writing my own library to work with Robot and I want to save the class object. I want the object to be created and saved once at the suite setup and keep using that same object for the entire test suite. Is there a way to do that?

Aristalibrary.py

```
import pyeapi

active_conn = None


class AristaLibrary:
    def __init__(self, proto="https", hostname='localhost',
                 username="admin", passwd="admin", port="443"):
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.proto = proto
        self.port = port
        self.username = username
        self.passwd = passwd

    def connect_to(self, proto, hostname, username, passwd, port):
        proto = str(proto)
        hostname = str(hostname)
        username = str(username)
        passwd = str(passwd)
        port = str(port)
        active_conn = pyeapi.connect(proto, hostname, username, passwd, port)
        return active_conn

    def enable(self, conn, command):
        return conn.execute([command])

    def get_active_connection(self):
        return active_conn
```

loginsight_sshlib_demo.txt

```
*** Setting ***
Library    BuiltIn
Library    String
Library    AristaLibrary

*** Variables ***
${hostname}    192.168.117.20
${username}    admin
${password}    admin
${port}        80
${proto}       http

*** Test Cases ***

Test Aristalibrary
    ${node}=    Connect To     ${proto}    ${hostname}    ${username}         ${password}    ${port}
    LOG    ${node}    level=DEBUG

Test Persistance of variables
    ${node}=     Get Active Connection     
    ${output}=    Enable    ${node}    show version
    LOG    ${output}    level=DEBUG

*** Keywords ***
Open Connection and Login
    Open Connection    ${hostname}
    Login    ${username}    ${password}
    Write     enable
    ${Output}=    Read 
    Log    ${Output}    level=INFO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Creating suite variables in test cases

The BuiltIn library has a keyword named [Set Suite Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) which lets you set a variable that is global for the whole suite. All you need to do is call this after creating your object:

```
${node}=    Connect To     ${proto}    ${hostname}    ${username}         ${password}    ${port}
Set Suite Variable   ${node}
```

From that point on, `${node}` will be available to all test cases.

### Creating suite variables in python code

You can have your library call the same `Set Suite Variable` keyword from within the library if you don't want the extra step in your test case. For example:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
class AristaLibrary:
    ...
    def connect_to(self, proto, hostname, username, passwd, port):
        ...
        active_conn = pyeapi.connect(proto, hostname, username, passwd, port)
        BuiltIn().set_suite_variable("${node}", active_conn)
        return active_conn
```

Doing the above will set the variable `${node}` when you call the `connect_to` keyword.

While this is an intriguing solution, it might lead to confusing test cases since it won't be apparent where `${node}` is getting set just by reading the test.

See the section named [Using Robot Framework's internal modules](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-robot-framework-s-internal-modules) in the robot framework user's guide for more information about calling keywords from python code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the library life cycle to match the testing suite life cycle.

Just define the following at the beginning of your library:

```
ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'
```

For example,

```
class ExampleLibrary:

ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'

def __init__(self):
    self._counter = 0

def count(self):
    self._counter += 1
    print self._counter

def clear_counter(self):
    self._counter = 0
```

Every global variable you define in the library, would be available for the library throughout the testing suite.