# Robot / Sikuli Integration - Keeping objects intact through test cases

Tags: python, robotframework, sikuli

Attempting to run Sikuli scripts with integrated Robot Framework to do automated testing on the GUI a program.

The program has a large number of windows in seperate processes. Sikuli has a native App() command which helps keep track of them, however the App() call takes a non-neglible amount of time to execute. For this reason, I create a dictionary of App() objects on start-up to be referenced later. The code below is for reference to show the structure and not the full or actual code.

Example Code:

```
 class myLib(object): 
    def startProgram(self):
        self.program = Program(args)
        self.program.start()
        self.program.createAppDictionary()

    def doSomething(self, area)
        self.program.dictionary['a'].click(area)

 class Program(object): 
    def createAppDictionary(self): 
        for key, obj in dict(self.config.items('Section')).items():              
            self.dictionary[obj] = App(obj)
```

Robot Framework Test File:

```
 ***Settings***
 Library  myLib
 Suite Setup    Start Program

 ***Test Cases***
 Do Stuff
     Do Something   Here
     Do Something   There
```

The above fails from an Attribute Error - 'str' does not have attribute 'dictionary' because program has converted to a string from an object.
Making small changes and running myLib as a sikuli script works fine.

Is there a way to have objects created in setup persist in the python code through test cases? Is my only options to create them all as Variables, then have them passed to the method calls in each test case?

Searched heavily in the Robot User Guide but it did not cover this scenario. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Also to be clear [Other Robot Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376954/saving-class-objects-in-robot-framework?rq=1)
may be a solution, but not the optimal one based on the structure of existing code.

Comment: Are you familiar with [ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope), and have you tried setting it to "GLOBAL" or "TEST SUITE"?

Comment: Clearly I was not familiar enough. Setting the library scope properly made the objects carry over. The sad thing is I remember perusing that part of the User Guide a few times but must not have read it with the proper amount of attention. 

Thank you for timely, concise, and most importantly CORRECT solution to my issue. (Seeing your reply in the other thread- you were actually the responder I was hoping to get for this.)